# viewing contacts without my iphone in my presence

Tags: iphone

I never forget my Iphone at home and oh course the day I did I need it like emergency status. My boyfriend and I share a car and I have to get out to ventura for my job and need to tell my boss if I can go or not within the next 30min. So I need to get my boyfriends cell number but I don't have it memorized. Is there anyway I can view my contacts thru my email or messanger?

Answer (score 2):

If you store them with an iCloud account you can go to http://iCloud.com/ to see them. Log in with your iCloud/AppleID account information and you can see your contacts on the website.

Similarly, if your iPhone syncs contacts with http://gmail.com/ or http://outlook.com/ or some other provider, you could use a web browsers to log onto your account at that website and see your contacts thusly.

Comment: Likewise, your contacts may sync with whatever email provider you use even if it's not iCloud (Gmail, Outlook.com, etc).